# Unable to remove item from array using Mongoose / UpdateOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Node.js application in which I am trying to remove an object from an array when an API endpoint is hit. I so far have been unable to get it to update/remove the object. Currently, the below query returns with no error but upon checking into my DB I am still seeing it. Below is my query and basic response (I will be adding more but that is outside the scope of this question). I have also included a sample of my data model.
In the below data model I am trying to remove the whole object from the foo array as it is no longer needed.
Code

```
const ID = req.params.id
await FooBar.updateOne({foo: {$elemMatch: {v_code: ID}}}, { $pull: {v_code: ID}}, (err) => {
   if(err) return res.json({success: false, err})
   return res.json({success: true, id: ID})
})
```

Data model

```
{
  bar: [
     {
       foo: [
         {
             v_code: <>
             _id: <>
          }
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

I'm sure this has been asked for in other questions but none specific to my data model. I've tried piecing together multiple SO posts and that is how I got the $elemmatch and the $pull portions of my query and so far I've had zero luck

Comment: Check out the example in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne) for getting the number of documents matched and modified.  Is your query matching any documents?

Comment: @Joe It should be matching a document, I have checked the mongo atlas console and see one that has the correct value for the key I'm trying to find. I just did as you suggested and tried to see the number of documents returned, it shows 0. Not sure why, I have confirmed that the key/value is vaild though maybe because the element isn't top level? I can't target the `v_code` directly in the `elemmeatch` since it also appears (different value) in an array of old values for `foo`

Comment: MongoDB query operators are type sensitive.  Make sure the type of `ID` matching the type of the data in the database.  It seems from the data model that `foo` is nested in `bar`, have you tried to match `{"bar.foo.v_code": ID}`?

Comment: @Joe Both are strings thought so and just did a small test of console.log to confirm and I was correct

Comment: Maybe the selector is invalid for the query?

Comment: Just tested this in the mongo atlas console and it find the correct document however the updateOne says it doesn't find any on it `'units.tenants.abut_code': ID`

Comment: Try `FooBar.findOne` with an empty query to see what the model returns.

Comment: @Joe It returns one document fine - not the one I am trying to update but a different one. If I change it to find then it returns both documents in the DB

Comment: test with `find` to craft the query that will match the document you want, then try `updateOne` with the same one.

Comment: @Joe Copy/paste my query from my comment 8 minutes ago returns the correct document. Maybe I could try `findOneAndUpdate` and update that way? Though it looks same as updateOne

Answer (score 0):

give the following command a try:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        "bar.foo.v_code": ID
    },
    {
        $pull: { bar: { foo: { $elemMatch: { v_code: ID } } } }
    }
)
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/iqJki-mnHSJ